# How to count string in column with select unique string by other column

Tags: postgresql

Trying to solve the problem find that, but it is not what i need...

```
select distinct column1, count(column2) from table group by column1;


    column1      column2
    aaa          type1
    bbb          type3
    ccc          type1
    aaa          type1
    aaa          type2
    aaa          type1
    ccc          type3
    aaa          type1
    bbb          type3
    aaa          type3
    aaa          type3
```

Expected result is:

```
    aaa type1 = 4, type2 = 1, type3 = 2
    bbb type3 = 2
    ccc type1 = 1, type3 = 2
```

Comment: then use column_2 for grouping

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    column1, 
    string_agg(format('%s = %s', column2, count), ', ') counts
from (
    select *, count(column2) 
    from test 
    group by 1, 2
    order by 1, 2
    ) s
group by 1
order by 1

 column1 |             counts              
---------+---------------------------------
 aaa     | type1 = 4, type2 = 1, type3 = 2
 bbb     | type3 = 2
 ccc     | type1 = 1, type3 = 1
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your expected output this is what I think your are after.

Use a `COUNT` function with a nested `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT column1, 
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type1Count,
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type2' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type2Count,
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type3' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type3Count
FROM Yourtable 
GROUP BY column1
```

Output:

```
Column1 Type1Count Type2Count Type3Count
aaa     4          1          2
bbb     0          0          2
ccc     1          0          1
```

Or to make it exactly as you wanted it (not recommended):

```
SELECT column1, 
'type1 = ' || COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type1Count,
'type2 = ' || COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type2' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type2Count,
'type3 = ' || COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type3' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type3Count
FROM Yourtable 
GROUP BY column1
```

Output:

```
Column1 Type1Count  Type2Count  Type3Count
aaa     type1 = 4   type2 = 1   type3 = 2
bbb     type1 = 0   type2 = 0   type3 = 2
ccc     type1 = 1   type2 = 0   type3 = 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but data in table is dynamic, and what if i don't know values in column2 from the begining? i can't write something like WHEN 'type1'

Comment: You could use a `SQL Pivot` Function more than likely.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Duly noted and amended :)

Comment: Please, and what about if there is one else column0, how make query show values that corresponding column1?

Comment: in previous context query

Comment: Any one help please? :)